# fetch() is fired before eventlistener on button is activated - Chuck Norris API

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

This is weird, what am I missing.

I am trying to get this API to send me random Chuck Norris quotes on a button click.

However, as soon as I refresh the page I get a new quote. I'd just like it to supply me with a new quote once I submit / click the button.

Please see the HMTL and JS below:

```
<body>

  <div>

    <button id="xxx"> GET A CHUCK QUOTE</button>

    <h1 id="chuck-quote"></h1>

  </div>


<script>

const chuck_button = document.getElementById('xxx');

chuck_button.addEventListener('click', function () {

  fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random') 
    .then(response =>  {
      return response.json();
    }).then( data => {
      const chuck_quote = document.getElementById('chuck-quote');
      chuck_quote.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data.value);
    })
  }());

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: I guess Chuck Norris can send quotes without any requests and endpoints

Comment: Chuck Norris knows when his quotes are requested beforehand, and first sends them, then receives the request :)

Comment: Just so you know, this was happening because the syntax you're using.  It is known as an ['immediately invoked function expression'](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-an-immediately-invoked-function-expression-a0ed32b66c18) and will immediately run, or invoke, a function right after defining it.

Comment: I think the comments section here is going to explode.

Comment: @Dan lol I just didn't see anyone mention the 'technical' term for why this was happening - wanted to make sure you had something solid to go on, other than "just remove the `()`" -- well what the heck is the `()` anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `()` in the line `}());`. Otherwise the function is directly called.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the `addEventListener` function at the time of setting it, I removed the `()` and it works fine.

```js
const chuck_button = document.getElementById('xxx');

chuck_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
      const chuck_quote = document.getElementById('chuck-quote');
      chuck_quote.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data.value);
    })
});
```

```html
<div>

  <button id="xxx"> GET A CHUCK QUOTE</button>

  <h1 id="chuck-quote"></h1>

</div>
```